# WPF Color Picker Implementation

Tags: c#, wpf

I have to create a color picker in my WPF application. When I click on any color, the code of that color should come in a textbox. I googled a lot but found nothing matching my requirement. Please share if you have done like this before.

Comment: This control, like mentionned below, already exist, so it's better to use this one than trying to recreate it, unless you have some really specific issue that you can't solve with it.

Comment: "I searched, but none of it was plug and play code, and I don't want to do any actual programming, so do it for me maybe?"

Comment: Recommend searching NuGet for "wpf colorpicker" and "wpf color picker" for possible solutions. The answers here are useful, but may become outdated for newer platforms, or may not be free.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

As Jodha said, you should use the Color Picker Control from the WpfToolkit Extended. Implementing the Color Picker Control is easy, simply do something like this:

Put this in your Window object:

```
xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
```

And this wherever you want your color picker.

```
<xctk:ColorPicker Name="ClrPcker_Background" SelectedColorChanged="ClrPcker_Background_SelectedColorChanged"></xctk:ColorPicker>
```

Then, all you have to do is use the SelectedColorChanged event to change the text in the textbox, like this:

```
private void ClrPcker_Background_SelectedColorChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<Color> e)
{
    TextBox.Text = "#" + ClrPcker_Background.SelectedColor.R.ToString() + ClrPcker_Background.SelectedColor.G.ToString() + ClrPcker_Background.SelectedColor.B.ToString();
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You can also bind the `ColorPicker.SelectedColorProperty` to a `System.Windows.Media.Color` property and bind the `TextBox` to the property and use a `Converter` to change it to the ARGB value, that way you can use the `TextBox` to change the color as well.

Comment: Getting error: Colorpicker does not exist in xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit" in my xaml file

Comment: @NareshKumar I just download the Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit and use the assembly instead.

Comment: @NareshKumar Yeah, did you actually download and install the Toolkit?

Comment: Is it possible to open the ColorPicker dialogue with a menu item click or button click? Thanks.

Comment: Good one, @Bob. Element naming and using events make this die-hard MVVM fan a tad uncomfortable.

Comment: I'm getting a "XamlParseException:The invocation of the constructor on type 'Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.ColorPicker' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception."  Anyone know anything about that?

Comment: Worked great after changing `RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<Color> e` to `EventArgs e` and deleting `R.`, `G.` and `B.`. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 17):

You can check the [Color Picker Control](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/ColorPicker) of  [WpfToolKit Extended](http://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit). This toolkit has many useful controls.

Comment: For people looking for this control, the project is now available on GitHub at https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit

Comment: Unfortunatelly their License says: for Non-Commercial Use only. You must buy a subscription if you want to use it commercially.

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way is to use **ColorDialog** which were used in WinForms.

```
 System.Windows.Forms.ColorDialog colorDialog = new System.Windows.Forms.ColorDialog();
 if (colorDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
 {
      DrawBallColorBtn.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(colorDialog.Color.A, colorDialog.Color.R, colorDialog.Color.G, colorDialog.Color.B));
      _drawBallColor = colorDialog.Color.Name.ToLower();
 }
```

**If you are targeting to a .NetCore 3.x add the following to the .csproj file**

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms> 
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use this code that I wrote. [Here is the full code](https://gist.github.com/SnowyPainter/49b698af1f48daa205e364f767628f4d)

UserControl.xaml

```
<StackPanel x:Name="PickerPanel" Orientation="Vertical" Background="White">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="210" MouseDown="RgbGradient_MouseDown">
            <Grid.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="White"/>
                    <GradientStop x:Name="MiddleStop" Color="#FF787878" Offset="0.5"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Grid.Background>
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="SpectrumGrid" Height="40" MouseLeftButtonDown="SpectrumGrid_MouseLeftButtonDown">
            
        </Grid>
        <TextBlock x:Name="HexCode" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>

    </StackPanel>
```

UserControl.xaml.cs

```
    public partial class ColorPicker : UserControl
    {
        public RGB Selected = new RGB();
        private double currH = 360;

        public ColorPicker()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var g6 = HSV.GradientSpectrum();

            LinearGradientBrush gradientBrush = new LinearGradientBrush();
            gradientBrush.StartPoint = new Point(0, 0);
            gradientBrush.EndPoint = new Point(1, 0);
            for (int i = 0; i < g6.Length; i++) {
                GradientStop stop = new GradientStop(g6[i].Color(), (i) * 0.16);
                gradientBrush.GradientStops.Add(stop);
            }
            SpectrumGrid.Opacity = 1;
            SpectrumGrid.Background = gradientBrush;

            MiddleStop.Color = HSV.RGBFromHSV(0, 1f, 1f).Color();
        }

        private void RgbGradient_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.LeftButton == System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                var pos = e.GetPosition(sender as Canvas);
                var x = pos.X;
                var y = pos.Y;
                RGB c; 
                if (x < Width / 2)
                {
                    c = HSV.RGBFromHSV(currH, 1f, x / (Width / 2));
                }
                else
                {
                    c = HSV.RGBFromHSV(currH, (Width / 2 - (x - Width / 2)) / Width, 1f);
                }
                HexCode.Background = new SolidColorBrush(c.Color());
                HexCode.Text = "#" + c.Hex();
                Selected = c;
            }
            
        }

        private void SpectrumGrid_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.LeftButton == System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                var x = e.GetPosition(SpectrumGrid).X;
                SpectrumGridBar.Margin = new Thickness(x, 0, 0, 0);
                currH = 360 * (x / this.Width);
                Debug.WriteLine(currH);
                MiddleStop.Color = HSV.RGBFromHSV(currH, 1f, 1f).Color();
            }
        }
    }

    public class RGB
    {
        public byte R { get; set; }
        public byte G { get; set; }
        public byte B { get; set; }
        public RGB() 
        {
            R = 0xff;
            G = 0xff;
            B = 0xff;
        }
        public RGB(double r, double g, double b)
        {
            if (r > 255 || g > 255 || b > 255) throw new Exception("RGB must be under 255 (1byte)");
            R = (byte)r;
            G = (byte)g;
            B = (byte)b;
        }
        public string Hex()
        {
            return BitConverter.ToString(new byte[] { R, G, B }).Replace("-", string.Empty);
        }
        public Color Color()
        {
            var color = new Color();
            color.R = R;
            color.G = G;
            color.B = B;
            color.A = 255;
            return color;
        }
    }
    public static class HSV
    {
        public static RGB[] GetSpectrum()
        {
            RGB[] rgbs = new RGB[360];

            for (int h = 0; h < 360; h++)
            {
                rgbs[h] = RGBFromHSV(h, 1f, 1f);
            }
            return rgbs;
        }
        public static RGB[] GradientSpectrum()
        {
            RGB[] rgbs = new RGB[7];

            for (int h = 0; h < 7; h++)
            {
                rgbs[h] = RGBFromHSV(h*60, 1f, 1f);
            }
            return rgbs;
        }
        public static RGB RGBFromHSV(double h, double s, double v)
        {
            if (h > 360 || h < 0 || s > 1 || s < 0 || v > 1 || v < 0)
                return null;

            double c = v * s;
            double x = c *(1 - Math.Abs((h / 60 % 2) - 1));
            double m = v - c;

            double r = 0, g = 0, b = 0;

            if (h < 60)
            {
                r = c;
                g = x;
            }
            else if(h < 120)
            {
                r = x;
                g = c;
            }
            else if(h < 180)
            {
                g = c;
                b = x;
            }
            else if(h < 240)
            {
                g = x;
                b = c;
            }
            else if(h < 300)
            {
                r = x;
                b = c;
            }
            else if(h <= 360)
            {
                r = c;
                b = x;
            }

            return new RGB((r+m)*255, (g + m) * 255, (b + m) * 255);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is quite problematic. RgbGradient_MouseDown is not defined, to start with

Comment: Also, you use hsv to rgb conversion which sometimes returns null. I suggest to change it to subroutine from site: https://www.programmingalgorithms.com/algorithm/hsv-to-rgb/

Comment: Function for picking color on RGBgrid did not give correct result for me, so I took away most of it and made strainghtforward implementation with winapi: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23583817/get-canvas-color-at-point

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your task, but I made color select dialog for WPF, look at [WPFColorLib](https://github.com/LexaGV/WPFColorLib) - hope it helps!