# RenderTargetBitmap.Render() won't render the opacity mask

Tags: c#, wpf, image, background, user-controls

I'm working to make a ColorPicker for my WPF app (I know about Extended Toolkit) and I've copied the xaml from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32514853/3914724) and it's working well but now I need to get the color is pointing the mouse. As hue is inside `Canvas` I've tried this:

```
Rectangle o = sender as Rectangle;
Canvas picker = ((Canvas)((VisualBrush)o.Fill).Visual);

Point point = e.GetPosition(picker);
RenderTargetBitmap render = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)picker.RenderSize.Width, (int)picker.RenderSize.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Default);

render.Render(picker);

image.Source = render;

if ((point.X <= render.PixelWidth) && (point.Y <= render.PixelHeight)) {
    var crop = new CroppedBitmap(render, new Int32Rect((int)point.X, (int)point.X, 1, 1));

    var pixels = new byte[4];
    crop.CopyPixels(pixels, 4, 0);

    selectedColor = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, pixels[2], pixels[1], pixels[0]));
    selectedColorRect.Fill = selectedColor;
}
```

}

on my mouse move event but `render.Render(picker)` won't render the opacity mask used to make the gradient.

**EDIT**
[image: Rectangle vs render]

The left is the original rectangle and in the right side is the result of the `render.Render(picker); image.Source = render;`, as you can see the right side is not applying the opacity mask.

Comment: Finally I've found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23583817/get-canvas-color-at-point)